# Are there any online chess tournaments for beginners( or new players)?

Tags: tournament, fide, online-chess, beginner

I have been playing online chess for a long time on sites like lichess and chess.com. But I have never played in any FIDE or AICF organized tournament. In this pandemic are there any online tournaments for new players organized by FIDE or AICF?

Answer (score 1):

There are online tournaments organized by FIDE (https://new.arena.myfide.net). They are more or less like lichess tournaments and you get a special online FIDE rating and you can receive special online titles (https://www.notion.so/FIDE-Online-Arena-Titles-045a5cbfb0994e0b9c04e05ee44c0491). To my best knowledge, there are no tournaments in which you can receive real FIDE points. I think because cheating is always a problem in online games.